# Error with onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android

Getting an error and not sure why.

I'm trying to get icons beside the icon of my app and the title of my app at the top of the screen.

I've tried to implement the onCreateOptionsMenu method however I'm getting this error.

'The method inflate(int, Menu) in the type MenuInflater is not applicable for the arguments (int, Menu).

This is the code I tried

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I've read that sometimes it can be related to the theme or the SDK version you're trying to target however I've checked both and they're fine. Version 11 is the min and I have the Holo.Light theme currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using ActionBarSherlock? If so, you have to use

```
getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.testmenu, menu);
```

Comment: Pretty sure I'm not using ActionBarSherlock, just the native Action Bar

Comment: What is your import for `Menu` - it should be `android.view.Menu` if you are using the native ActionBar.

Comment: It's android.view.MenuInflater , I thought you needed that package to edit the action bar so you can add icons into it?

Comment: @MOS182 - I asked about `Menu`, not `MenuInflater`. If you don't have an import for `android.view.Menu`, that certainly may be the cause.

Comment: I didn't have the android.view.Menu package imported, had android.view.MenuInflater instead